# Comparing two List<MyClass> in C#

Tags: c#, .net, list, iequatable, iequalitycomparer

I have a class called

```
MyClass
```

This class inherits IEquatable and implements equals the way I need it to. (Meaning: when I compare two MyClass tyupe objects individually in code, it works)

I then create two List:

```
var ListA = new List<MyClass>();
var ListB = new List<MyClass>();
// Add distinct objects that are equal to one another to 
// ListA and ListB in such a way that they are not added in the same order.
```

When I go to compare ListA and ListB, should I get true?

```
ListA.Equals(ListB)==true; //???
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the following

```
ListA.SequenceEquals(ListB);
```

SequenceEquals is an extension method available on the `Enumerable` class.  This is available by default in C# 3.5 projects as it comes with System.Linq

Answer (score 2):

[Enumerable.SequenceEqual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, no, you should not get true. `List` and `List<T>` do not define .Equals, so they inherit Object.Equals, which checks the following:

```
public static bool Equals(object objA, object objB)
{
    return ((objA == objB) || (((objA != null) && (objB != null)) && objA.Equals(objB)));
}
```

And `objA.Equals(objB)` is virtual. If I recall correctly, the default implementation just checks for reference equality (pointing to the same object in memory), so your code would return false.